# Error: invalid instruction suffix for `push'

Tags: .asmx

Buenas, hoy programando en asm me encontré con este error y bueno como son mis comienzos en este lenguaje despues de un tiempo buscando en internet, no he encontrado me gustaría que me faciliten el fallo que estoy cometiendo, cuento con una maquina ubuntu 32-bit.
code:

```
.data
i: .int 21, 15, 24, 11, 6, 50, 32, 80, 10, 0

s: .asciz "The number is: %d\n"

.text
.global main
main:
        movl $0, %ecx
loop:
        pushl %ecx
        pushl i(,%ecx,4)
        pushl $s
        call printf

        addl $8, %esp
        popl %ecx
        incl %ecx
        cmpl $0, i(,%ecx,4)
        jne loop

        movl $1, %eax
        movl $0, %ebx
        int $0x80
```

Error:

```
t7_printf.s: Assembler messages:
t7_printf.s:11: Error: invalid instruction suffix for `push'
t7_printf.s:12: Error: invalid instruction suffix for `push'
t7_printf.s:13: Error: invalid instruction suffix for `push'
t7_printf.s:17: Error: invalid instruction suffix for `pop'
```